# What are the constants in the sklearn kernel syntax?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

On the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#exp-sine-squared-kernel), I often see kernels written out like this:

`kernel = 1**2 * ExpSineSquared(...)`

What is the `1**2`? (Aside from being equal to 1)

Comment: `1**2` is the one to the power of two. in other words, it's the same as `pow(1, 2)`.

Comment: @Anwarvic, I don't think the question is "what is this in Python", but rather, "what role does this play in the definition of the kernel"?

Comment: Thanks @Chris, you are correct in your interpretation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `1**2` is in fact a hyperparameter of the kernel. For example, the squared exponential kernel as shown below has a parameter in front of the exponential, v^2. This represents the average deviation from the mean. This is the same for other kernels.

Therefore 1**2 * RBF() is equivalent to:

[image: squared exponential kernel]

where v = 1